# Next.js image optimization not saving images in cache

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image, notion-api

I'm making a Next.js blog and I'm using Notion as the CMS. I'm using Next 13 with appDir.

The thing is, files and media have a 1-hour expiry timeframe using the Notion API, so the source links only work within that hour. I originally thought that ISR revalidation would solve the problem, but Next.js serves a stale render the first time a user loads the page after the revalidation duration (stale-while-revalidate), meaning the first time a user loads the page in a while, it sends a stale website with images that don't work.

I then tried next/image with Image Optimization, since I read somewhere that images get saved in the cache so theoretically the stale pages should still work, but it's not working. I've also tried adding a 30-day `minimumCacheTTL` in next.config.js, but nothing seemed to change.

Any ideas? Using external images on Notion would work, but I wanted to see if I could find a solution for Notion-hosted images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar boat right now (I think). I'm building a Notion backed blog and I want to be able to cache articles indefinitely. My conclusion so far in assessing this issue is that you can't really do caching all that nicely by just using the S3 links as-is. Either you regenerate pages before links expire, or you additionally have an automation pipe generate external mirrors of assets embedded in the articles. I guess it goes without saying that inserting external links manually is not an attractive option.

In development, my current strategy is to simply use the S3 links - fetch data from Notion on the first render, but revalidate before links expire (1 hour).

```
export const getStaticProps:StaticPropFn<Props> = async ctx => {

    const id = (ctx.params?.id as any) || "";
    // fetch data from notion
    const page = await fetchPage(id);
    // extract properties I want to use from the page object
    const properties = mapViewObject(page.page);
    // notion objects -> html string
    const renderResult = await NotionRender.blocks2HTML(page.blocks);

    return {
        props: {
            properties,
            html:renderResult.html,
        },
        
        revalidate:3000, // seconds, revalidate before links expire
    };
};
```

For production, I'm thinking I'll have to set up a pipeline that uploads media to a public CDN mirror whenever a blog article changes - and then replace all the S3 links with links from my CDN where the file names are the Notion block ids.

```
https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8b83d1f5-874d-42d8-95e8-f9b8b18a32c0.png
```

becomes

```
cdn.mysite.com/8b83d1f5-874d-42d8-95e8-f9b8b18a32c0.png
```

I came across a tutorial where someone was using [Pipedream](https://pipedream.com/) to post process blog articles, and there seem to be some decent built in options for Notion. I'm sure you could use any similar such service though.

I hope this may be of some help. I don't know how people do this usually but it's the approach I'm sticking with until I find something better.